# Mod Security SecStatusEngine

Tags: mod-security2

When i enabled the SecStatusEngine of mod security in their configuration file then restarting the apache shows an error

Invalid command 'SecStatusEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 1):

*SecStatusEngine* command has been added to mod_security *2.8* and you're probably using mod_security *2.7.** or older.

Please upgrade mod_security or remove *SecStatusEngine* from your config file.